# IdentityServer4 for BotFramework using ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: botframework, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

Can we use `IdentityServer4` to connect to this disco:

```
https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration
```

I don't quite understand the disco and is not quite informative. What I understand is there is a requirement to register the Bot and we will get the app Id and app secret from the bot portal site.

I tested using `client_credentials` as this is just an API, and it works by using Postman/Fiddler. But how do we relate this with the bot framework secrets key to be able to run on Bot Emulator? I can connect to the bot emulator without the `[Authorize]` attribute.

And the other one is more familiar to me:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

`client_crendtials
         |           |
         V           V
    [Bot API] -> [IDS4/STS] -> [Microsoft Bot Portal]
                       ^             ^
                       |             |
                      appId+appPassword`